# For a homomorphism $f:G \rightarrow H$, is it true that for distinct $x$'s, $f(x_1)=f(x_2)= ... =y \implies y = 1_H$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In one proof that the kernel is non-trivial if the homomorphism $f:G \rightarrow H$ is not injective, you start by assuming $f(x_1)=y, f(x_2)=y ... , f(x_n)=y, ...$ From here, you can derive $f(x_2 * x_1^{-1})=yy^{-1}=1_H$, where $1_H$ is the identity of $H$.

For some reason I was under the impression for the longest time that (and I might not word this correctly) the identity was the *only* member of $H$ that multiple members of $G$ map to, or in other words, we know that $y=1_H$. Is this the case, and if so, could you direct me to a proof? Otherwise, are there any obvious examples where its not the case?

Comment: The kernle of a group homomorphism can never be empty, because it always contains the identity element.

Comment: Right, sorry, edited

Comment: In groups (and in rings, and in vector spaces) we focus on the elements that map to the identity because (i) the morphism is one-to-one if and only if the only element that maps to the identity is the identity; and (ii) checking what maps to zero is generally easier than checking that $f(x)=f(y)$ implies $x=y$. Also, the isomorphism theorems allow you to "code" the image in terms of what maps to $0$. 
Consider an easy example: map $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} = \{\overline{0},\overline{1}\}$, integers modulo $2$, by mapping odds to $\overline{0}$ and evens to $\overline{1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is *never* the case (unless $f(x)=1_H$ for all $x$).  Indeed, notice that if $a\in \ker(f)$, then $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)=1_Hf(b)=f(b)$ for all $b\in G$.  So if $f$ is not injective, then for any $b\in G$, there is more than one element of $G$ that maps to $f(b)$ (namely, $ab$ for any $a\in \ker(f)$).

More precisely, we can say that every element of the image of $f$ has the same number of preimages.  This is because for any element $f(b)$ in the image of $f$, there is a bijection $\ker(f)$ and its preimage $f^{-1}(\{f(b)\})$, mapping $a\in\ker(f)$ to $ab$.

Comment: Outstanding answer, that clarifies this so much for me.

Answer (score 0):

The first Isomorphism Theorem states that $G \cong f(G) / ker(f)$ so if we denote $ker(f)=N$, we get that for any $g\in G$ all the elements of the form $g\cdot n$ for any $n\in N$ (i.e. $gN$) map to the same element: $f(g)$

Comment: It's unclear to me how this answers my question.

Comment: @JamesHurley: Given any quotient map, and any $g\notin N$, then $g$ and $gn$ map to the same thing for any $n\in N$, and not to the identity of the quotient.